# Lua Sol - Acess object script variable in runtime

Tags: lua

Scenario example

Object A
Object B

both have lua script abc.lua

In abc.lua have a variable call "MyMobileNumber" and both start with "No_Number"

During some amount of runtime
Object A has new mobile number "MyMobileNumber" and is "123"
Object B also have new mobile number and is "987"

ok right now Object B want to access Object A "MyMobileNumber" which give 123. how do I access that?
it is using DoFile or require. how the syntax to access them in Lua? Thank you

Comment: if both are defined in the same file, why do you think you need require? you mention the same file name for both?

Comment: ok, they using same script as template, but the variable value is different. how to deal in this case?